# echo parameters in bash

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script but echo is taking all my parameters as string literals

for example in this code:

```
echo -ne "Hello World"
```

produces `-ne Hello World`

How do I get it to actually use the parameters "ne" ?

Cheers.

Comment: just so you know, I tried
eval echo -ne "Hello"
and ofcourse that didn't work either, I thought it was worth a shot though

Comment: What does `echo $BASH_VERSION` print?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have `#!/bin/bash` declared at the top of the script? If not try to add it. It's probably executing under `sh` and not `bash`, that's why you're seeing this behaviour.

Comment: That was the problem actually,
I had it as #!/bin/sh

teaches me not to copy my code without looking again......

Answer (score 8):

Consider using the `printf` command rather than `echo`; its behavior is much more uniform across different shells and operating systems.

Comment: Complete agreement here; `echo` is a mess of incompatibilities waiting to bite you....

Comment: It's probably ok as long as (a) no arguments start with `-` (which means avoiding `-n`), and (b) no arguments contain any backslash characters.  For example `echo Hello, world` or `echo Done processing` should be safe.  On the other hand, there's something to be said for using `printf` uniformly rather than having to decide for each line of output whether you can get away with using `echo` or not.  (On the other other hand, a non-GNU `printf --version` will probably print `"--version"`.)

Answer (score 2):

In sh the echo is a command not a executable, so you can use /bin/echo to force the use of the executable and ensure that your parameters will work.